# Showing a set is Jordan measurable (using Fubini's theorem?)

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Let $E_1 \subset\Bbb R^m$, $E_2 \subset \Bbb R^{m+n} \;$ two Jordan measurable sets. Show that: $$E=\{(x,y)\in E_2 \;| \;x\in E_1\}= E_2 \cap (E_1 \times\Bbb R^n) \subset \Bbb R^{m+n}$$

is jordan measurable.

I only know to prove Jordan measurability by showing the boundary is a null set. I recently learned about Fubini's theorem and I thought about using it here, but didn't know how. Is there an elegant solution to this? or only by definition?